# Different schema name on correlation table - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to have a different schema name on correlation tabels than [dbo]?

I'm using code first.

Example:

ApplicationRole.cs

```
public class ApplicationRole
{
    public Guid ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ADGroup> ADGroups { get; set; }
}
```

ADGroup.cs

```
public class ADGroup
{
    public Guid ADGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationRoleConfiguration.cs

```
public class ApplicationRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("T_ApplicationRoles", "LabConfig");

        this.HasKey(a => a.ApplicationRoleId);

        this.Property(t => t.ApplicationRoleId)
            .HasColumnName("ApplicationRole_GUID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);


    }
}
```

ADGroupConfiguration.cs

```
public class ADGroupConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ADGroup>
{
    public ADGroupConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("T_ADGroups", "LabConfig");

        this.HasKey(a => a.ADGroupId);

        this.Property(t => t.ADGroupId)
            .HasColumnName("ADGroup_GUID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // correlation table should also get schema [LabConfig]
        this.HasMany(o => o.ApplicationRoles)
            .WithMany(r => r.ADGroups)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("ADGroup_GUID");
                m.MapRightKey("ApplicationRole_GUID");
                ToTable("T_ApplicationRoleADGroups", "LabConfig");
            });
    }
}
```

But the result on the database is always:

- [LabConfig].[T_ADGroups]
- [LabConfig].[T_ApplicationRoles]
- [**dbo**].[ApplicationRoleADGroups]

Any ideas? I spent hours for this to work with my desired schema without any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case i did something stupid i didn't see...

Compare the original ADGroupConfiguration.cs with this:

```
public class ADGroupConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ADGroup>
{
    public ADGroupConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("T_ADGroups", "LabConfig");

        this.HasKey(a => a.ADGroupId);

        this.Property(a => a.ADGroupId)
            .HasColumnName("ADGroup_GUID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired();

        // the Mapping was causing the error.
        // this Mapping is correct now
        this.HasMany(o => o.ApplicationRoles)
            .WithMany(r => r.ADGroups)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("ADGroup_GUID")
                            .MapRightKey("ApplicationRole_GUID")
                            .ToTable("T_ApplicationRoleADGroups", "LabConfig"));

    }
}
```

Hence my mapping had an error it was hiding the real problem i was searching for...

Always double check the mappings!